# How to obtein batery, memory and CPU consumption in RPi?

Tags: performance, erlang, cpu-usage, raspberry-pi3

I have an erlang process running in my RPi and I want to study its batery, memory and CPU consuption, to compare it with a C++ implementation of the same process.

Is there anyway to generate or collect this information?

Pls, let me know :D, I'm starting with RPi

Comment: Can you provide some specifics? Tell us what you have tried so far, what tools you are using to accomplish this, and the exact information you are trying to get. I imagine there should be command line tools that can provide this info.

Comment: I want to analyse (with graphs) the power, memory and CPU consumption of some processes. I have tried some tools such as htop and Conky, but I dont know how store these values. Or if there is other tool to achieve better my purpose.